# Не могу подключить SedNL

Tags: сеть, cmake

Есть такая библиотека - [SedNL](http://sednl.zenol.fr/doc/) (для работы с сетью), но я не знаю как её подключить. Там в архиве есть какие-то файлы для `CMake`, есть папка `src` и `include`.

Я пробовал закинуть `include` в папку с проектом (работаю в `Code::Blocks`), но ошибки полезли. Возможно, кто-нибудь умеет ее устанавливать или есть какая-то статья?

Помогите, пожалуйста, или посоветуйте другую библиотеку для нетворкинга, кроме `Asio`, так как она слишком сложная для меня. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/documentation/), по этой библиотеке полно документации и опыта в сети, так что Вам должно быть проще. SedNL тоже можно использовать и никакой проблемы в этом нет, но Вы, видимо, совсем не понимаете, что с ней делать, а значит лучше выбрать то решение, где лучше документация.

Comment: Я понимаю само програмирование с сетями, но не знаю как подключать библеотеки.

Comment: В этом-то и проблема, поэтому лучше используйте те библиотеки, у которых богатая документация, иначе будет сложно. Попробуйте POCO, как я уже сказал. А если уж очень сильно хочется SedNL, то её сначала надо собрать и только потом использовать. [Здесь](https://github.com/Zenol/sednl) написано как её собрать. Но, повторюсь, если Вы ранее не имели дело со сборкой библиотек, то SedNL не лучший выбор, при сборке и добавлении библиотек Вам придётся додумывать некоторые моменты самостоятельно, а без опыта это будет довольно сложно.